# How to get the value from the input tag in java?

Tags: java, html

```
<input type="text" name="n1" value="howru"/>
```

The given code above is the question and i want to know how we can extract value i.e howru from value using java and the given code is not jsp i wanted solution in core java no jsp tags are used and this is normal html code

Comment: You need to insert way more detail. Specifically, what http Java server are you using and what does your receiving method looks like.

Comment: receiving method is a listener which invoke the db after fetching the value

Comment: Ah, if receiving method is a listener just query the servlet for the post map then.

Comment: sry i wanted it in normal like using jsoup or any other things i cant use it using servlet,or jsp tags

Comment: When I said you need to insert WAY more detail... I meant it. We have no idea what server you're using nor what your code looks like. While you've been here for more than a year all your questions are down voted because of lack of effort. You must make some effort to be helped!

Answer (score 0):

As the question isn't clear,but it seems like you want to extract value from the tag without using jsp and servlet, and let's just add a couple of more tags for better understanding.
This can be done using JSOUP: https://jsoup.org/cookbook/

```
 String inputTag = "<input type=\"text\"   name=\"n1\" value=\"howru\"/>"
    + "<input type=\"text\"  id=\"textField2\" name=\"n2\" value=\"howru2\"/>"
    + "<input type=\"hidden\"  id=\"hiddenField\" name=\"n3\"value=\"howru3\"/>";

    Document document = Jsoup.parse(inputTag);

    Elements elementByTag = document.select("input[type=text]");
    System.out.println("Element By Tag(First Input Tag--text):" + elementByTag.get(0).attr("value"));
    System.out.println("Element By Tag(Second Input Tag--text):" + elementByTag.get(1).attr("value"));

    Element elementByID = document.getElementById("textField2");
    System.out.println("Element By ID(Second Input Tag--text):" + elementByID.attr("value"));

    elementByID = document.getElementById("hiddenField");
    System.out.println("Element By ID(Hidden Field):" + elementByID.attr("value"));
```

Output

```
Element By Tag(First Input Tag--text):howru
Element By Tag(Second Input Tag--text):howru2
Element By ID(Second Input Tag--text):howru2
Element By ID(Hidden Field):howru3
```